# Android Support Library for 4+ devices?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, android-support-library

Do you think is it a good practice to use `Android Support Library` if my app will support only devices which working on Android 4 ? Or it is unnecessary?

Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android Support package is not only for backports. For example, if you want to use `ViewPager`, you will need to use the Android Support package. And, in 2014, the Android Support package might get backports of things that are not in whatever your planned `android:minSdkVersion` is.

If, instead, you are asking whether it is necessary to use `FragmentActivity`, the AppCompat action bar, and similar backports, no, you will not need those.

Answer (score 0):

Use the support library only if functions you want to use don't work on one of the API levels you target.